# dev c++ doesn't compile std::function and __declspec(property

Tags: c++

why doesn't `std::function<int(int)> functionName` and `__declspec(property(get = getNumber, put = putNumber)) int number` work on dev c++?

I copied countless sample codes and they all return errors..

EDIT:

```
class Class {
private:
    int _number;

    int getNumber() {
        return _number;
    }

    void putNumber(int number) {
        _number = number;
    }

public:
    __declspec(property(get = getNumber, put = putNumber)) int number;
    std::function<int(int)> functionName;
};
```

and if I just include this class it will give me an error..

Comment: It might be helpful to post some of those examples.

Comment: What version of dev-c++?

Comment: you most likely have an ancient compiler, dev c++ is quite known for that

Comment: added some examples!!

Answer (score 4):

**Problem**

- [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) is a C++11 new feature and it seems the version of compiler beside your Dev-C++ is obsolete.
- [`__declspec(property(...))`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yhfk0thd%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) is a *Microsoft Specific* keyword and is meaningful for MSVC++ compilers only.

**Solution**

Update the compiler to support `std::function`. Remove `__declspec(property(...))` and put `public` before `int getNumber()` :

```
class Class {
private:
    int _number;

public:
    int getNumber() {
        return _number;
    }

    void putNumber(int number) {
        _number = number;
    }

    std::function<int(int)> functionName;
};
```

Comment: how can I get those effects on dev c++ then? Because I HAVE to use dev at school since it's the only compiler they allow. How can I work around that?

Comment: Now I'm curious if the school is using Bloodshed Dev-C++ or the fork that's actually being maintained.

Comment: At least it's a step up from Turbo C++.

Comment: The problem is that then I can't access properties of properties.. I wanted to be able to do something like: object.property.propertyOfThePreviousProperty = something;

Comment: I said _property_ is a MS specific keyword, you can't have them. Forget them and rewrite your program in another way.